# Are PS4 controllers region locked for any odd reason?

Tags: controllers, ps4

Upon searching for a new controller for the PS4, I noticed that there were red and blue SONY official controllers that were coming from Asia. Upon further investigation, I learned  that they are not sold in the US.

If I were to buy one of these controllers from someone who imported it, will it work 100% with my US version PS4?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[No, they aren't, as was confirmed before release](http://www.officialplaystationmagazine.co.uk/2013/09/23/from-twitter-with-love-all-the-crucial-ps4-info-revealed-so-far/). I'm not sure a controller has ever been region locked actually, and the PS4 is completely region free for games.

Comment: Yeah I wasn't sure on if they could be or not. I'd just hate to waste money on something and have it be unusable.....and that article is so wrong about the jealousy thing....it costs more to import rather than buy it local...ehhh

Comment: I would actually be impressed if they went to the effort of region locking a controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at this site this comes directly from Playstations FAQ

There are no region locks with games nor hardware

http://www.siliconera.com/2013/10/30/massive-playstation-4-faq-answers-questions/

Comment: I once could not connect a controller to my PS4, despite both of them coming from the same region.
The problem was that my console had already had 4 controllers connected to it, that's why it wouldn't let me connect a fifth.
I first had to reset one of mine before I was able to connect the new controller.
Maybe you were experiencing the same thing.

Answer (score -2):

I think that ps4 controllers are region locked, because I tried connecting my freind's ps4 controller to my ps4 knowing both our consoles are from different regions. And his controller did not connect to my ps4, and my controller did not connect to his ps4.

Comment: This directly contradicts existing and established answers.  Do you have a source for this statement?

Comment: @user143365 since I posted this question I have since ordered a Japanese controller and it works just fine. You need to pair each controller to the playstation you want to use it on. If you sync it to yours it will only work on yours until you sync it to your friends playstation.